# Convert Single data type to string in inno setup

Tags: inno-setup

I have a code which has a variable of Single datatype , but i want to display is in a message box. For example

```
VAR data:Single;
data:=0;
data:=5633.67+1290.965;
Msgbox('The sum of Fractional number is-:'+IntTostr(data),mbinformation,MB_OK);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are at least two options I can think of right now. The first one is `FloatToStr` function, which is undocumented, or the official way of using [`Format`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_format.htm) function, which gives you much better flexibility in specifying format that you want. Here is an example of `FloatToStr` function:

```
var
  S: string;
  Value: Single;
begin
  Value := 1.2345;

  S := FloatToStr(Value);
  MsgBox('Value is: ' + S, mbInformation, MB_OK);
end;
```

And here is an example that uses [`Format`](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_format.htm) function. There is shown how to display a floating value in the `General` format and how to show the same value with 2 decimal places by using `Fixed` format. For more information about formats refer to the Delphi help for the [`Format`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.SysUtils.Format) function:

```
var
  S: string;
  Value: Single;
begin
  Value := 1.2345;

  S := Format('Value is: %g', [Value]);
  MsgBox(S, mbInformation, MB_OK);
  S := Format('Value is: %.2f', [Value]);
  MsgBox(S, mbInformation, MB_OK);
end;
```